# Multi-layer neural network won't predict negative values

Tags: perl, neural-network, classification, backpropagation

I have implemented a multilayer perceptron to predict the sin of input vectors. The vectors consist of four -1,0,1's chosen at random and a bias set to 1. The network should predict the sin of sum of the vectors contents.

eg Input = <0,1,-1,0,1> Output = Sin(0+1+(-1)+0+1)

The problem I am having is that the network will never predict a negative value and many of the vectors' sin values are negative. It predicts all positive or zero outputs perfectly. I am presuming that there is a problem with updating the weights, which are updated after every epoch. Has anyone encountered this problem with NN's before? Any help at all would be great!!

note: The network has 5inputs,6hidden units in 1 hidden layer and 1 output.I am using a sigmoid function on the activations hidden and output layers, and have tried tonnes of learning rates (currently 0.1);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Being a long time since I looked into multilayer perceptrons hence take this with a grain of salt.

I'd rescale your problem domain to the [0,1] domain instead of [-1,1]. If you take a look at the logistic function graph:

[image]

It generates values between [0,1]. I do not expect it to produce negative results. I might be wrong, tough.

**EDIT**:

You can actually extend the logistic function to your problem domain. Use the [generalized logistic curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function) setting A and K parameters to the boundaries of your domain.

Another option is the hyperbolic tangent, which goes from [-1,+1] and has no constants to set up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does make sense! Il have to have a look around for a function that can allow for negative values. Unfortunately I cant change the problem domain as its an assignment for college. Thanks again!

Comment: @B. Bowles Updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thats great I'l give that a try now! There are a lot of params in that formula that don't apply to this network, and maths is definatly not my strongpoint. It certainly sounds like the way forward though.

Comment: @B. Bowles The hyperbolic tangent also goes from [-1,+1] and has no constants to set up. I just remembered it now.

Comment: Thats great, and far easier to implement!! my $a = exp($activation); my $b = exp(-$activation); $output = ($a-$b)/($a+$b); ...Just incase anyones interested in using it in future. Thanks a million

Answer (score 4):

There are many different kinds of activation functions, many of which are designed to output a value from 0 to 1. If you're using a function that only outputs between 0 and 1, try adjusting it so that it outputs between 1 and -1. If you were using [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) I would tell you to use the [FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC](http://fann.sourceforge.net/html/r2030.html) activation function.

Comment: unfortunatly I can't make use of any libs for this assignment, if only! I have a look into how that works though, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has already been answered, allow me to share my experience. I have been trying to approximate Sine function using a **1--4--1** neural network. i.e,
[image]
And similar to your case, I am not allowed to use any high level API like TensorFlow. Moreover I am bound to use C++ over Python3! (BTW, I mostly prefer C++).

I used **Sigmoid** activation and its derivative defined as:

```
double sigmoid(double x) 
{ 
   return 1.0f / (1.0f + exp(-x)); 
}

double Sigmoid_derivative(double x)
{
   return x * (1.0f - x);
}
```

And this is what I got after **10,000 epochs**, training the network on **20 Training Examples**.
[image]

As, you can see, the network  didn't feel like the negative curve. So, I changed the activation function to **Tanh**.

```
double tanh(double x)
{
   return (exp(x)-exp(-x))/(exp(x)+exp(-x));
}

double tanh_derivative(double x)
{
   return 1.0f - x*x ;
}
```

And surprisingly, after half the epochs, (i.e., **5000**), I got a far better curve.
[image] And we all know that it will significantly improve on using more hidden neurons, more epochs and better (and more) training example. Also, shuffling the data is important too!