# Training nnet and avNNet models with caret when the output has negatives

Tags: r, r-caret, nnet

My question is about the typical feed-forward single-hidden-layer backprop neural network, as implemented in package nnet, and trained with `train()` in package caret. This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105718/multi-layer-neural-network-wont-predict-negative-values) but in the context of the nnet and caret packages in R.

I demonstrate the problem with a simple regression example where `Y = sin(X) + small error`:

> 1. `raw Y ~ raw X:` predicted outputs are uniformly zero where raw `Y < 0`.
> 2. `scaled Y (to 0-1) ~ raw X`: solution looks great; see code below.

The code is as follows

```
library(nnet)
X <- t(t(runif(200, -pi, pi)))
Y <- t(t(sin(X)))           # Y ~ sin(X)
Y <- Y + rnorm(200, 0, .05) # Add a little noise
Y_01 <- (Y - min(Y))/diff(range(Y)) # Y linearly transformed to have range 0-1.
plot(X,Y)
plot(X, Y_01)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(X, Y, Y_01)); names(dat) <- c("X", "Y", "Y_01")
head(dat)
plot(dat)

nnfit1 <- nnet(formula = Y ~ X, data = dat, maxit = 2000, size = 8, decay = 1e-4)
nnpred1 <- predict(nnfit1, dat)
plot(X, nnpred1)

nnfit2 <- nnet(formula = Y_01 ~ X, data = dat, maxit = 2000, size = 8, decay = 1e-4)
nnpred2 <- predict(nnfit2, dat)
plot(X, nnpred2)
```

When using `train()` in caret, there is a preProcess option but it only scales the *inputs*. `train(..., method = "nnet", ...)` appears to be using the raw `Y` values; see code below.

```
library(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10) 
nnet_grid <- expand.grid(.decay = 10^seq(-4, -1, 1), .size = c(8))
nnfit3 <- train(Y ~ X, dat, method = "nnet", maxit = 2000, 
            trControl = ctrl, tuneGrid = nnet_grid, preProcess = "range")
nnfit3
nnpred3 <- predict(nnfit3, dat)
plot(X, nnpred3)
```

Of course, I could linearly transform the `Y` variable(s) to have a positive range, but then my predictions will be on the wrong scale. Though this is only a minor headache, I'm wondering if there is a better solution for training nnet or avNNet models with caret when the output has negative values.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on cross validated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116123) by user [topepo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3468/topepo)

The relevant part of their answer is:

> Since Y is roughly between -1 and 1 you should also use `linout = TRUE` in your `nnet` and `train` calls.